# linux + dose each security kernel rpm will install the relevant initrd and vmlinuz files under /boot

Tags: linux, kernel, yum, initrd

I just print the kernel rpms that need to install on my redhat machine (version 6.5)

# yum list-security --security | grep kernel-[0-9]

```
    RHSA-2014:1143 security kernel-2.6.18-371.12.1.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2014:1959 security kernel-2.6.18-400.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2014:2008 security kernel-2.6.18-400.1.1.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2015:0164 security kernel-2.6.18-402.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2015:0783 security kernel-2.6.18-404.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2015:1042 security kernel-2.6.18-406.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2016:0045 security kernel-2.6.18-408.el5.x86_64
    RHSA-2016:0450 security kernel-2.6.18-409.el5.x86_64
```

in case I want to install all  security kernel rpms ( as displayed )
is that mean that all 8 initrd & vmlinuz kernels files will be installed under /boot ?

I am asking this question because I have small free available size on /boot

remark - the yum command that installed all the security packages is:

```
     yum -y update --security
```

example what I have now under /boot:

```
# ls /boot
   System.map-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5  grub                             lost+found                      vmlinuz-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5
   config-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5      initrd-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5.img  symvers-   2.6.18-371.11.1.el5.gz
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could add how much space exactly is free in /boot. `df -Pm /boot` should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in case I want to install all security kernel rpms ( as displayed ) is that mean that all 8 initrd & vmlinuz kernels files will be installed under /boot ?
>
> I am asking this question because I have small free available size on
> /boot

Basically yum would only install the latest kernel security update, as there's no point in installing older updates. And depending what you have configued for `installonlypkgs` and `installonly_limit` options in `/etc/yum.conf` it will only install the new kernel, then remove the old kernel package. Although the default is to keep the newest 3 kernels, if I remember correctly.